# How do I optimize these two lines?

Tags: php, optimization, variable-declaration

So, I have these two lines of PHP.

```
$total_row_count = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM %s',$table_name),$db));
$total_row_count = $total_row_count['count'];`
```

Is there any way to change the first declaration of $total_row_count so the 2nd line isn't necessary?

Something to this effect (I know this isn't functional code).

```
$total_row_count = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM %s',$table_name),$db))['count'];
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: I did find this, is there a better way?
$total_row_count = array_shift(mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(sprintf('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM %s',$table_name),$db)));

Comment: You should actually be using a lot ***more*** code than that. You need *error handling* right after the query. Wrap the whole thing in a function if you don't like repeating it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You second snippet is perfectly functional *since PHP 5.4*. It's called direct array dereferencing.

However, you should never ever do `mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query(...))`. The `mysql_query` call may fail and return `false`, which propagates ugly errors into `mysql_fetch_assoc`. **You need error handling!**

```
$result = mysql_query(...);
if (!$result) {
    die(mysql_error());
    // or
    return false;
    // or
    throw new Exception(mysql_error());
    // or whatever other error handling strategy you have
}

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$count = $row['count'];
```

If this is too much code for you to repeat often, wrap it in a function.

```
function getCount() {
    $result = mysql_query(...);
    ...
    return $row['count'];
}
```